# unix regex: match from end of string until white space character

Tags: regex, unix, grep

The git command:

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-status -r <commit hash>
```

generates a list that looks kinda like this:

```
D    path/to/deleted/file.txt
A    path/to/added/file.txt
A    path/to/added/file.asd
M    path/to/modified/file.txt
```

I want to grep out only the added and modified (A or M) txt files and their paths. I know I can do like this:

```
grep -v "^D"
```

to not include the deleted files.

and

```
grep -o "\w*.txt$"
```

to only get the txt files. But this command does not give me the path to the files. Since `\w` only matches the word. Is there any other wildcard that will match until the whitespace character (so that it removes the A/M with corresponding whitespace)?

Comment: Using awk it can be: `awk '$2 ~ /\.txt$/'`

Comment: So, you only want the .txt files? There is also an .asd file - should that NOT be shown in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\S` to match anything that isn't whitespace.

```
grep -o '\S*\.txt$'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk /^A/^M/'{$0=$NF} 1'
path/to/added/file.txt
path/to/added/file.asd
path/to/modified/file.txt
$
```